# Exporting MySQL table data: "into outfile" fails, directory stays NULL after editing variables in cnf files

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm pretty new to SQL, MySQL and Docker. I'm running a Docker MySQL container (I believe).

### My problem:

In MySQL, the command

```
select * from [tablename] into outfile [csv-filename];
```

fails with the message

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

### What I've tried:

```
select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
```

outputs a value of **NULL**.

Then, I changed/added the line

```
secure_file_priv= "/home/"
```

into both of the following files within the container:

- /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf

Still, "select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;" in MySQL returns **NULL** and "(...) into outfile (...);" fails as described above.

Any clues are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be you missed the `[mysqld]` section for the configuration file however here is a complete example:

```
$ mkdir conf
$ mkdir home
$ mkdir datadir
$  echo -e '[mysqld]\nsecure_file_priv= "/home/"' | tee conf/native.cnf
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv= "/home/"

$ cat conf/native.cnf
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv= "/home/"

$ docker run -v $PWD/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
             -v $PWD/home:/home  \
             -v $PWD/datadir:/var/lib/mysql \
             -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw \
             --name mysql \
             mysql:5.7
```

Another terminal:

```
$  docker exec -ti mysql  mysql -pmy-secret-pw -e 'select @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv'

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /home/                    |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: This indeed works, but now how do I change the secure_file_priv variable in an exisiting container?

Comment: You generally don't. You recreate the container with the right configuration, this way it is repeatable. Note database container can have volume mounts for /var/lib/mysql to preserve data, or use the initialization aspects of the container.

Comment: I'm getting closer! Adding the volume with docker run as suggested gives me the fatal error "InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!" Is this a common problem with an easy solution that I missed?

Comment: looks like you've taking the install data directory from an incompatible instance. Look carefully at how each was created and what mysql version is in the container rather than the datadir.

Comment: I think I got what I need regarding my original question, thank you! But could you edit it and include the part "recreating container with right configuration and volume mount"?

Comment: Indeed changing the "mysql:5.7" to "mysql:8.0" (in my case) did the trick.